# 'Reader' object has no attribute 'tell' error with jsonlines and cloud storage

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing a cloud function to extract data from an API in the following format:

```
[{'_id': '123qasd', 'description': 'stuff here', 'userId': 'xxxx', 'billable': False, 'taskId': 'asddf1234', 'projectId': '5e11gg55', 'timeInterval': {'start': '2020-05-16T09:00:00+02:00', 'end': '2020-05-16T13:00:00+02:00', 'duration': 14400}, 'taskName': 'Production', 'tags': [], 'isLocked': True, 'customFields': [], 'userName': 'Dupond', 'userEmail': 'stuff@mail.com', 'projectName': 'my project', 'projectColor': '#607D8B', 'clientName': 'my client', 'clientId': 'xxxxxxxx'}, {'_id': '123qasd', 'description': 'stuff here', 'userId': 'xxxx', 'billable': False, 'taskId': 'asddf1234', 'projectId': '5e11gg55', 'timeInterval': {'start': '2020-05-16T09:00:00+02:00', 'end': '2020-05-16T13:00:00+02:00', 'duration': 14400}, 'taskName': 'Production', 'tags': [], 'isLocked': True, 'customFields': [], 'userName': 'Dupond', 'userEmail': 'stuff@mail.com', 'projectName': 'my project', 'projectColor': '#607D8B', 'clientName': 'my client', 'clientId': 'xxxxxxxx'}, {'_id': '123qasd', 'description': 'stuff here', 'userId': 'xxxx', 'billable': False, 'taskId': 'asddf1234', 'projectId': '5e11gg55', 'timeInterval': {'start': '2020-05-16T09:00:00+02:00', 'end': '2020-05-16T13:00:00+02:00', 'duration': 14400}, 'taskName': 'Production', 'tags': [], 'isLocked': True, 'customFields': [], 'userName': 'Dupond', 'userEmail': 'stuff@mail.com', 'projectName': 'my project', 'projectColor': '#607D8B', 'clientName': 'my client', 'clientId': 'xxxxxxxx'}]
```

I want to send this data to Cloud Storage and then, read them with BigQuery. In order to do this I need to convert json to ndjson.

I'm using `jsonlines` to handle the conversion. Here is an extract of my function:

```
with jsonlines.open(f'/tmp/output.jsonl', "w") as writer:
    writer.write(data)

date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
destination_blob_name = '{}'.format(date)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
with jsonlines.open('/tmp/output.jsonl') as reader:
    blob.upload_from_file(reader)
```

I have the following error `'Reader' object has no attribute 'tell'`

What's wrong?

Comment: Hey Same Issue, have you found the issue ? :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work! use just normal file open.

```
 with open('output.jsonl', 'rb') as f:
        blob.upload_from_file(f)
```